# Using ocamldoc with packs

Tags: ocaml, ocamldoc

I have an ocamlbuild project which includes some files in a subdirectory with an .mlpack file listing them.

e.g. I have a file `support/logging.ml` which defines the module `Support.Logging`. The `_tags` file says `"support": for-pack(Support)`.

This all builds and runs fine. But how can I generate docs for this using ocamldoc?

The most recent post I found was [ocamldoc generation and packed files](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-mirage/2011-August/msg00024.html) from 2011, which suggests using `ocp-pack` to generate one large .ml file and pass that to `ocamldoc`. However, that doesn't take into account the build order, so the generated module doesn't work due to forward references.

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution I'm now using in my Makefile. It does work, and cross-references into the Support module work:

```
doc:
    ocp-pack -o support.ml.tmp support/logging.ml support/common.ml support/utils.ml support/basedir.ml support/qdom.ml support/system.ml
    echo '(** General support code; not 0install-specific *)' > support.ml
    cat support.ml.tmp >> support.ml
    rm support.ml.tmp
    $(OCAMLBUILD) 0install.docdir/index.html
    rm support.ml
```

It's hacky because:

- You have to list the support.ml files in build order, by hand
- The Makefile adds the doc comments for Support (otherwise, it takes the description of the first sub-module, which you don't want)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is described in [the following bugreport](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=4209). Handling `-pack` inside ocamldoc requires an implementation effort that the maintainer is not motivated to perform, and so far nobody stepped up to contribute a patch for this feature.

In the meantime, you can easily copy your `foo.mlpack` file into a `foo.odocl` generating the documentation of the separate submodules. That's only an imperfect workaround as the doc will talk about `X` rather than `Foo.X`, but that's a least-effort solution.